# How to trigger infix type display in REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

If I create my own type with two arguments:

```
class !:[A, B]
```

then creating an instance of it in the REPL does not display its type the way I want:

```
scala> new !:[Int, Int]
res18: !:[Int,Int] = $bang$colon@5eb1479
```

Instead, I would like it to display like this:

```
scala> new !:[Int, Int]
res18: Int !: Int = $bang$colon@5eb1479
```

Is this possible in scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infix display for symbolic types is default in Scala 2.12.2. The change was made in [this pull request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5589).

It also added annotation `showAsInfix` in package `scala.annotation` to give you control in cases you need to alter default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you could override the toString method and control the second part of the output, like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

class A[X, Y] (implicit val tt: TypeTag[X], implicit val ty: TypeTag[Y]) {
  override def toString() = typeOf[X] + " !: " + typeOf[Y]
}
new A[Int, Int]()
```

Outputs

```
res15: A[Int,Int] = Int !: Int
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I would really like to be able to display the `A[Int, Int]` differently. I already overrided the toString method in my case.